# Handling Ajax errors

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, xmlhttprequest

I have a function to upload a file using Ajax. It works fine in a normal situation. Now I'm trying to differentiate between a "Network error" and a "File does not exist error". The code looks basically like this:

```
$.ajax({
  type: 'PUT',
  url: upload_url,
  processData: false,
  data: selected_file,
  error: function(xhr, status, error) {
    logger.error("Error uploading file");
  }
});
```

**This is what I've discovered so far:**

In both cases, the parameters for the Ajax error function are very similar: `xhr.status` is 0, `status` is "error" and `error` is "".

I can clearly see different error codes in the Chrome console: `net::ERR_INTERNET_DISCONNECTED` and `net::err_file_not_found` but I can't/don't know how to find this codes from the Ajax error function.

Comment: `xhr.status` should work - it contains the HTTP response code being returned. What is the exact response from your server?

Comment: xhr.status is 0 in both cases. The request doesn't reach the server.

Comment: Then something fundamental went wrong with sending the request. Is the URL on the same domain and port as the originating page?

Comment: Also not sure about browser support for PUT, what version of Chrome is this in?

Comment: If the request doesn't reach the server then it's not being sent. This would explain why the status code is `0`. This implies there is an error encoding the data to be sent. What is the content of `selected_file`?

Comment: ... and how large is it?

Comment: Maybe I didn't explain myself well ennough. In a normal situation my code works perfectly well. Now I want to be able to handle possible errors. For that, I'm making the errors to happen in purpose to see what happens. In one case I set the network offline, in the other case I remove the file before is being sent.

Comment: @Pekka웃 The Chrome version that I'm using is 54.0.2840.98

Comment: Ah, OK... hmm, not sure whether those errors are catchable then. You could `console.log` the entire `xhr` and `error` objects  to see whether there's any hints in any of their properties. Other than that this may not be possible, don't know

Comment: Either way, your question might benefit from an edit explaining what you're trying to do, in case someone comes along who knows about this.

Comment: Yes, I've logged the `xhr`, `status` and `error` but they don't show any clue about the error. I've edited the question, I hope it explains better the problem.